# Intellij not exporting correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, bukkit

So, I have set up Intellij to export a JAR file, and its not going to the correct output directory.

I am using the CraftBukkit library.

In Project Structure I have a new Artifact with:

The extracted CraftBukkit JAR
The compiled output
The plugin.yml

The project output is set

There is a manifest file and the main file is org.bukkit.craftbukkit.main

But the JAR isn't exporting to the directory, I can't find the JAR at all.

The strange thing is I did the exact thing and it worked for another project, so I don't know what the problem is.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result? Also you may want to tag this with [minecraft] [bukkit] people who stalk those tags tend to be friendlier towards beginner programmers struggling with making plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with IntelliJ's artifact exporting system, not sure if you have fixed it yet but here's the solution that worked for me.

Head to your plugin's `.idea/artifacts` directory then click on `artifact_name.xml` file and change the `<output-path>` value to wherever you want to export it to, you can also use `$USER_HOME$` instead of manually typing `C:/Users/YourName`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with build tooling (i.e. compiling and packaging your plugins) I HIGHLY HIGHLY recommend using a build system, even if you use the defaults.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8327-minecraft-development

Is a plugin for IntelliJ concentrating on project setup, and some Minecraft specific features while developing.

having a look at how the default gradle or default maven project setups work in that plugin will likely help you to learn the basics enough to automate the creation of your plugins.

Comment: I'm trying out the plugin, but the problem is the JAR file isn't exporting to the directory at all. It worked perfectly and automatically with another project, but not this one for some reason. I used to use Eclipse but after my classes being deleted by a bug I switched to Intellij.

Comment: How are you exporting it? My point was to use one of the build system templates the plugin can generate when making a new project. Also if this hasn't yet solved your issue, you shouldn't mark it as accepted yet.

Comment: This is one that I made a few months ago for Sponge, your process should be similar for starting with MCDev in Bukkit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCQK3gSMNjU&feature=youtu.be